# Expose Swift Files to Objective-C within Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a framework with Swift and Objective-C in it. I have the statement at the top of my Objective-C class `#import "MyFrameworkHeader.h"` which I thought would expose my swift code to my Objective-C class however the compiler still says the symbols don't exist, how can I expose my Swift classes to my Objective-C classes within the same Framework?

Comment: Would you like to be a little more specific about what you're doing?

Comment: @matt I've edited the question to be (hopefully) a lot less convoluted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ugh, after smacking my head for a few hours then finally posting this question, within a few minutes I found the answer:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_82

Under the header: "Importing Swift into Objective-C"

Comment: Also known as "rubber duck": http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281270/what-does-rubber-duck-mean-in-debug-help :)

Answer (score 2):

To get Objective-C to register your swift code you should go into your build settings and then see/set your project name, also see if the compatibility header option is checked to yes.

after that is set just go into your file and type #import "-Swift.h". I don't think you can import individual files with swift and Objective-C, you import all of your swift files at once. It's important that you make sure all of your swift files have no errors or you will get an error about this header not being defined. You might have to build your project with no errors for the file to get generated at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a **Bridging Header**.
This is a file that you import your Objective-C headers into that get exposed to Swift.

There are 2 ways to make one (as far as I know):

- The easiest way, in my opinion, is to add an existing Obj-C file to your swift project, or vice-versa. Xcode should ask you if you want to automatically configure a bridging header. Choose yes, and Xcode should make a file called something like 'project name'-bridging-header.h. In this file, import your files, so `#import "MyFrameworkHeader.h"` should do it.
- Make your own empty file with File > New File (Cmd+N) > Source > Header File. Call it whatever, and import your files like in the previous one. Before it will work, you have to enter the name of your bridging header file into a field in your Project Settings (In the first option, Xcode will do it for you).